# What are the Eight Enemies Not in the Kingdom Hearts Journal

Tags: kingdom-hearts

I read on a wiki that there are eight enemies in kingdom hearts one that never appear in the journal. Ansem was one, as he appears after the final save point. What are the other seven?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at this [Shadow Sora](http://www.khwiki.com/Shadow_Sora) article, the Trivia sections says:

> Shadow Sora is one of only eight enemies who do not have entries in Jiminy's Journal. The others are [AntiSora](http://www.khwiki.com/AntiSora), [Bit Sniper](http://www.khwiki.com/Bit_Sniper), the [Cave of Wonders Guardian](http://www.khwiki.com/Cave_of_Wonders_Guardian), [Chernabog](http://www.khwiki.com/Chernabog), the [Crank Tower](http://www.khwiki.com/Crank_Tower), the [Shark](http://www.khwiki.com/Shark), and [World of Chaos](http://www.khwiki.com/Game:World_of_Chaos).